# bash script to get command values in two files and write is a pattern to new file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cut

Bash script to get command values in two files and write is a pattern to new file

Need bash script to find common values in two files and write it to new file in certain pattern. I can get the common values but can't get the pattern work.

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
10
12
13
16
20
21
22
23
27
30

$ cat file2
1
2
3
4
8
10
12
13
16
20
21
22
23
27
```

`Desired output:`

```
1:4
8
10
12:13
16
20:23
27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the common lines, you can do something simple like

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1]=1} NR!=FNR && x[$1]' file1 file2
```

That leaves you with a list, and you need to group the elements in ranges.  That's a simple awk script:

```
awk 'NR==1 {s=l=$1; next} $1!=l+1 {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1} {l=$1} END {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1}'
```

Putting it all together:

```
    awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1]=1} NR!=FNR && x[$1]' file1 file2 | awk 'NR==1 {s=l=$1; next} $1!=l+1 {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1} {l=$1} END {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1}'
```

Explanation:

We keep track of the start of the current range and the last value we saw.

```
NR==1 {s=l=$1; next}
```

NR==1 only runs on the first line.  It will always be the first element of a range.  The next skips the other commands.

```
$1!=l+1 {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1}
```

If there is a break in a run, then the value of a given line ($1) will not be the value after the last line (l + 1) so we print out the range.  If the start and end are the same, we print out a single number; otherwise we print out the start followed by a colon followed by end.

```
{l=$1}
```

We update the last line *after* doing the range check.

```
END {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1}
```

We have to run the logic one more time at the end to print out the last range

Comment: so you'd connect the 2 with a pipe? Good luck to all.

Comment: works as advertised but `comm` on Linux complains files are not in sorted order, that's presumably because it expects lexically sorted, not numerically sorted files. But feeding lexically sorted files to `comm` breaks this approach.

Comment: GNU `comm` has a `--nocheck-order` option. POSIX `comm` uses the current locale, but I don't know if there is a predefined (or even a possible) locale that sorts strings numerically.

Comment: @chepner its better to avoid the gnu extension, especially since macs use the BSD variant which does not have that option.  I opted to replace it with a pure awk version

Comment: for the sorting "problem", there's always `comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sort -n`